# In Zend Framework using MultiDB Resource, how do I configure database fallback?

Tags: database, zend-framework, fallback

We use Zend Framework's MultiDB resource ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb )

I've been tasked with adding a new DB resource which has three endpoints for redundancy.  I'd like to configure MultiDB so if the connection to the first endpoint fails, it'll connect to the second and, if need be, third endpoint before giving up.

I tried setting resource.multidb.resourcename.host[] but that failed.  It looks like it will only accept a single endpoint.

Is there a way to configure fallback?  Or do I need to extend Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I've never tried *software-side* (not even sure if its really possible with zend framework "itself") fallback for database applications. And there's a good reason for it: Its simply the wrong place for it!

There are several stumbling blocks:

1. How do you manage to keep data persistent among several databases?
2. What happens if one database is down?

Assuming you're using MySQL: You might want to take a look at the *master - slave* replication of MySQL itself: [16.1.1. How to Set Up Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)

Even this might cause you headdeaches (espacially if you have to migrate existing data). I'm currently quite satisfied with a solution i came across several projects ago:
Instead of having the pain of handling redudancy by your own, simply hand the task to your database/sever itself!

The easiest solution I came across so far is setting up your database on an (from you webapplication itself independent) [failover vServer cluster](http://linux-vserver.org/Fail-over).

I'm sorry if my answer quite not match your question ... but it might be a thought-provoking impulse for an different approach.